# Eclipse Rename - Refactor hotkey inserts registered trademark symbol

Tags: eclipse, macos, pydev

Previously, using the ALT+COMMAND+R key combination after highlighting a variable name in a Java file would go into the rename refactor mode. Now, the key combination replaces the highlighted text with a registered trademark symbol. *How can I get the key combination to go into the rename refactor mode instead of inserting the symbol?*

The current file encoding is set to MacRoman, which is the default setting inherited from container. As far as I know, nothing here has changed.

I am using Eclipse Indigo (Build id: 20110615-0604) on Mac OS X 10.7.5. Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers 1.4.0.20110615-0550 and FreeMarker IDE SDK 1.1.0.v201006011046R-H111-GA are installed. I don't think there are any non-standard plugins.

The only recent change I can remember making is installing PyDev a few weeks ago. With the default PyDev installed, ALT+COMMAND+R opens a context menu in the lower right corner with 2 option: rename and set next symbol (this is in addition to replace the text with the symbol). I disabled the Set Next Symbol key binding in my preferences, restarted eclipse, and tried the key combo again. The text was still replaced by the symbol but the rename refactor mode was not entered did not open. I uninstalled PyDev, restarted eclipse, and tried the key combo again. The text was still replaced by the symbol.

Update (December, 2012): Another user on eclipse forums is having a similar issue: http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=rview&goto=990973

Update (January, 2013): I have opened [APSTUD-7664](https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/APSTUD-7664) in PyDev's Jira. Hopefully, a developer will pick it up and find a solution.

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue. I installed PyDev last night, and now I can't get refactor rename to work no matter what shortcut I bind it to. I would love a fix for this.

Comment: I have the same thing. outside eclipse, ALT+CMD+R doesn't yield the R symbol, only ALT+R does.

Comment: For now, I'm using CMD+1 to open a dialog, then selecting rename. My muscle memory is fighting my brain though.

Comment: You can type option-command-T, it is softer on your muscle memory.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Same problem here (OS X 10.7.5, Eclipse Juno for Java, build 20120614-1722, PyDev recently installed). The following solution worked for me:

1. Eclipse > Preferences... > General > Keys
2. Choose Rename - Refactoring (Category: Refactor - Java)
3. Click Unbind Command
4. Click Binding field and type Command-Option-R
5. Click OK

A possible clue as to what's going on (I don't know): the User column is set to "C" before fixing the binding, and set to "U" afterward.

Answer (score 10):

Ed's unbind/rebind trick didn't work for me, but changing "When" from "In Windows" to the more specific "Editing Java Source" seems to have done the trick.

I guess it's a bit more restrictive, but for my workflow Java is really the only place I'll be doing any refactoring.

Comment: The only problem with this solution is that the shortcut doesn't work anymore for renaming files from the Package Explorer...

Comment: At least it works though; I found the same thing with unbinding and rebinding unfortunately not working, but setting it to only when editing Java source works correctly. It may not work everywhere, but at least it works! Also, when renaming files in the package explorer you can use F2 instead.

Answer (score 4):

If anyone is still having this issue (and it is still an issue with the most recent Eclipse Kepler when you install PyDev), this is the solution that worked for me. It's very similar to Ed's, but I had to unbind on the PyDev command specifically.

Go into Preferences > General > Keys menu:

[image]

Filter by the word "refactor" in the filter box. What you'll see is that there's a conflict ("C" in user column):

[image]

You need to sort by the highlight the Rename - Refactoring command and sort by binding. Then remove the filter. This will show all conflicts (including the PyDev one that is fouling things up)

[image]

Click the PyDev command bound to the same key combination click "Unbind Command"

Now nothing will be bound to that key combination, so just go back up to the correct command, "Rename - Refactoring" and rebind Command-Option-R to it.

[image]

When you're finished, it will show as a User defined command (U in user column), but it will work properly in both the project menu and in the code editor. The only thing that won't work is the PyDev command that was bound to it. If you want, feel free to bind that command to an alternative key combination.

Answer (score 0):

I think .. the solution is full resetting. So i do as follow.
My environment is Eclipse kepller and Mac Mountain lion.

1. Terminate eclipse.
2. Copy workspace for safety. (Maybe its useless, but for safety...)
3. **Delete .metadata** hidden folder from workspace.
4. Start eclipse, then you see whole new workbench without projects!
5. Now, **import existing project** from your workspace folder.
6. That's all. Your default rename key is restored. And you have refreshed environment.

It's simple.

Have a nice development time.

Comment: I doubt it helps.  Or maybe it works by removing PyDev.  To restore defaults, use Preferences > General > Keys and press the [Restore Defaults] button near the bottom right.